# Running a async function in my INotifyPropertyChanged-class and the code doesnt run

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin

I am trying to make each listcell in a listview different depending what they clicked previously and I am doing this with a INotifyPropertyChanged.

I have a if/else code in my class but it doesn't run.. i get no color. 
If i for example us a color = Color.Green; inside my Public Current then it works. But not when I do this if/else statement it doesnt run.

This is my class:

```
public class Current : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
Color color;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Current()
    {
         RunThis ();
    }


    async void RunThis ()
    {
        var checkWhatOption = await parseAPI.WhatOption ();

        if ((checkWhatOption ["results"] as JArray).Count > 0) {

             color =  Color.Black;
        }
        else {
            color = Color.Red;
        }

    }

    public Color Color
    {
        set
        {
            if (color != value)
            {
                color = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Color"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return color;
        }

    }
  }
```

And in my XAML on the page where  I use it I have this code :

```
<Label BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}"  >  
<Label.BindingContext>
  <local:Current />
</Label.BindingContext>
```

UPDATED:

```
    public static async Task RunThis()
    {

        if ((Stringone ["results"] as JArray).Count > 0) {

            Color = Color.Black; //An object reference is required to access non-static member.
        }
        else {
            color = Color.Red; //An object reference is required to access non-static member.

        }

    }


protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        await Current.RunThis ();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are it is being blocked.

Your call to your `async` `RunThis` function from the constructor isn't using `await`, which of course you can't within the constructor.

Also try to change the `RunThis` function to something along the lines:-

```
public async Task RunThis()
{
   ..
}
```

And then find and appropriate place to call this using `await`, but not via a constructor.  Be sure that the caller has `async` specified also.

Comment: how can I call on it if i dont do it via the constructor? Maybe this would do it? protected override async void OnAppearing()
  {
//and put the code here?
  }

Comment: @William.John `protected async override void OnAppearing()` is available on the `ContentPage`.

Comment: yes. I use the class in my XAML though so iam not using it on code somewhere. should i just do a protected async override void OnAppearing() await Task.Delay (1000); and that will make it load?

Comment: @William.John Using a `Task.Delay` will unlikely solve your issue.

Comment: Check my updated code under the xaml code. Still doesnt work even though I get the "Test" message in my console. Is it blocked somehow?

Comment: `Current` is your class name.  As your doing `async void OnAppearing` I suspect `Current` does not derive from `ContentPage`.   Again, your still calling your own async method from the constructor.  Do you want to package up what you have and send over and I will take a quick look?

Comment: Updated code now. I think im getting closer now I get this error "//An object reference is required to access non-static member." When I try to use color.